# DiscriminatorFormula SQL

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, discriminator

I have a `mappedSuperClass` that I am deriving concrete implementations from.  What would be the SQL to get the `reportType.name` value to be able to add it to the child entities?

```
@MappedSuperclass
@Table(name = "report")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorFormula("select reportType.name from Report")  //HQL ????
@DiscriminatorValue(not null)  // catches everything left over
public abstract class Report<E extends Exception> {

     @OneToOne(mappedby="id")
     private ReportType reportType
     ...
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(“credit”)
public class CreditScoreReport<E extends Exception> extends Report<E> {
   public void doCreditScoreStuff(){
      ...
   }
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(“DMV”)
public class DmvReport<E extends Exception> extends Report<E> {
   public void doDmvStuff(){
      ...
   }
}

@Entity
public class ReportType {
    @id
    private Long id;
    @Column(name="name")
    private String name;

    // mutators, etc
}

REPORT_TYPE TABLE ENTRIES
| id | name   |
---------------
| 1  | DMV    |
| 2  | CREDIT |
| 3  | HEALTH |
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I originally wrote might work.  The only change I made was to make the discriminatorFormula native SQL